# Justify the given limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ ${\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'd like to know how to formally show this limit is zero.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}}=0$$

Comment: What have you tried to justify the given limit?  Reminder, this task is your task, so don't assign it to us.  Ask us for help, but don't ask us to do your work for you, and don't tell us to justify statements you were given to prove.

Comment: How can you show *informally*?

Comment: Yes, please show us you work in merely mastering how to show it informally?  If you can't do that, that's where you need to start.

Comment: Your sequence can be written as $f(1/\sqrt[4]{n})$, where $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[8]{1+x^8}-\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}}{x}$ and so your limit is the derivative at $0$ of $g(x)=\sqrt[8]{1+x^8}-\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: (not the only way through)

Think of it as $$\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[8]{(n+1)^2}=\frac {\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{(n+1)^2}}{\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[8]{(n+1)^2}}$$ then $$\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{(n+1)^2}=\frac {\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{(n+1)^2}}{\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[4]{(n+1)^2}}$$ and $$\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{(n+1)^2}=\frac {n^2+1-(n+1)^2}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{(n+1)^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}=\left(n^2\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)^{1/8}=n^{1/4}\left(1+\frac{1}{8n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)
$$
and
$$
\sqrt[4]{n+1}=\left(n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^{1/4}=n^{1/4}\left(1+\frac{1}{4n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)
$$
You get that

> $$
> \sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}=n^{1/4}\left(\frac{1}{8n^2}-\frac{1}{4n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
> $$

Answer (score 1):

$$(n^2+1)^{1/8}=n^{1/4}(1+n^{-2})^{1/8}=n^{1/4}+O(n^{-7/4}),$$
$$(n+1)^{1/4}=n^{1/4}(1+n^{-1})^{1/4}=n^{1/4}+O(n^{-3/4})$$
etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\frac{7}{4}>1$ and $$\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}=\frac{n^2-(n+1)^2}{\sqrt[8]{n^2+1)^7}+...+\sqrt[4]{(n+1)^7}}\rightarrow0$$

Comment: (one edit), and counting...  Initial answer was only the formula.

Comment: The first to post, in this case, is the first to post a wrong answer, and correct it only after two other users who were more careful in their work posted correct answers.